# angular js : Is it necessary to load all the controllers and factories / services in module file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, module, reference

NET MVC to one CRM application and using angular js for client side script.

I have come across several articles to use angular js and all of them have set controller and services / factories inside the module and they are loaded all in one time.

So my question is it necessary to load all controllers and services in module or I can separate those js and use in page by page whenever I need to use page wise?

I am navigating using ASP.NET MVC pattern not single page using angularjs route.

Comment: You can do this, yes. Might be hard depending on how much of page is reloaded on mvc route change. Also look at oc-lazy-load.

Comment: @AluanHaddad ok thanks I will analyze the pages and will decide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can separate those angularjs files and use one angularjs controller per page, but you need to register the modulename of the controller or service in the main module(app.js) inside the brackets[], like this:

```
//app.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','myApp.controller','myApp.create.controller'])
          .config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
              $routeProvider
              .when("/", {
                templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController',
                controllerAs: 'home'

              }).when("/create",{
                templateUrl: 'manage/create.html',
                controller: 'CreateController',
                controllerAs: 'create'
              })
          });

//HomeController.js
var module = angular.module('myApp.controller', ['myApp.service']);
module.controller('HomeController', ['HomeService',
    function (HomeService) {

        var self = this;
        self.EmpData = [];

        HomeService.getAllEmployeesTable().then(onSuccess, onError);

        function onSuccess(response) {
            self.EmpData = response.data;
        }
        function onError(error) {
            alert('Error fetching data');
        }
    }]);

//CreateController.js
var module = angular.module('myApp.create.controller',['myApp.create.service']);
module.controller('CreateController',['CreateService',
    function(CreateService){
        var self =this;

        self.person = {
            name : "", email:"",address:"",telephone:""
        }

        self.submitPerson = function(){
            console.log(self.person);
            CreateService.submitPerson(self.person).then(onSuccess,onError);
        }

        var onSuccess = function(response){
            alert("User has been added succesffully");
        }
        var onError = function(error){
            alert("Error creating person");
        }   
    }
]);
```

Comment: Not running in my case actually if you read my question carefully I am not applying single page app so no need to use route in my case. I am using asp.net mvc actionresult for navigation puropse so every time I have to load my module js first and then the respected page js and others ...